# how to do rollback in fastapi

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, fastapiusers

i am trying to save 2 record in to database,
in try block i have saved those two records :

```
session.add(rec_1)
await session.commit()
await session.refresh(rec_1)
```

i need rec_1 id, so i have saved and accessed in rec_2

```
session.add(rec_2)
await session.commit()
await session.refresh(rec_2)
```

in except block i have used session.rollback():

if any error occurs after saving the rec_1,
from the database rec_1 is not roll backing ,

if any error occurs i don't want to save the any of the records.

please guide me how to handle this situation,

Comment: What kind of database are you using? Are you using explicit transactions and have you disabled autocommit? Did you start a transaction first?